# jQuery hide div that contains certain text

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

On my website I have 3 types of employees

- barista
- barista01
- security
  and I would like to hide the barista01 option but leave the others as they are (please refere to the picture).

When i try to use `$("div:contains('barista01')").parent('div').hide();` I get a full black window hiding everything inside.
Is there anyway how to fix this?

Thank you in advanced
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfCVX.jpg)

Comment: Can you please share some HTML which you've given in Screenshot?

Comment: `<div class="hc-mt3" style="background-size: cover;">
<div class="hc-border hc-rounded hc-p2" style="border-color: gray; background-size: cover;">
<div style="background-size: cover;">
<div style="background-size: cover;">
         <div class="hc-inline-block hc-valign-middle hc-mr2" style="background-size: cover;">
            <div class="hc-inline-block hc-px1 hc-rounded" style="background-color: rgb(203, 232, 107); background-size: cover;">&nbsp;</div>
         </div>
         <div class="hc-inline-block hc-valign-middle" style="background-size: cover;">barista01</div>`

Comment: The space is so limited to enter more code...

Comment: If Class("hc-mt3) is fixed then you can use: $("div:contains('barista01')").parent('.hc-mt3').hide();

Comment: Thank you. It worked. How can I sing your answer as the right one?

Comment: I've added Answer, Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Class name ".hc-mt3" is fixed and will not change then you can target that class.
See Example Code: `$("div:contains('barista01')").parent('.hc-mt3').hide();`